# DotNetNuke vs Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, dotnetnuke

What is the difference between DotNetNuke CMS and visualStudio . i mean, is it better to use DotNetNuke over VisualStudio for Asp.net web site development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio is used to build DotNetNuke.  I would guess 98+% of all third party DotNetNuke coding (modules/provders/skins etc.) is done using Visual Studio.

If your purpose is to create a web site (e.g. organize the pages, and menus, add pictures, text, documents, manage users etc.) you can do all of that without writing any code by using DotNetNuke.  With Visual Studio you must write code to do even the simplest thing like add a page with some text.

If you need to create some very custom web site features, or integrate with other software systems, then you will probably need to write some code.  Pretty much any code that you write for platforms based on Microsoft's .Net technologies (including DotNetNuke) will be done using Visual Studio.

Comment: You most certainly don't need to write code just to have a page some text (unless you consider simple HTML code, which it's not), nor do you need to use Visual Studio for .Net code (there exist alternatives, such as SharpDevelop, MonoDevelop, and so on).

Answer (score 2):

Dotnetnuke is a Content Management System done in ASP.Net Technology. Visual Studio is the editor used to write ASP.Net code. (basically .Net projects). Dotnetnuke is an ASP.Net project which can be opened and edited in Visual Studio. You can create your own project instead of using Dotnetnuke which is a precreated project.

Answer (score 0):

dotnetnuke is more like joomla meaning its just a content management and visual studio is just an ide or editor.
you can develop your own DNN module using visual studio